Android Firebase Push Notification Limitation
I was testing data messages using Firebase's push notification service on Android and noticed that the app doesn't receive any data messages when the phone is connected to mobile data. However, when the device is connected to Wi-Fi, it appears to receive the data messages. Is this behavior documented anywhere?

@AlexMamo I have read here that, sometimes on App Standby Bucket the high priority firebase data message is restricted. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/notifying-your-users-with-fcm.html
